# Set the Coordinates of a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am working on a project right now. I have a multiple TextView on the screen. I want them to have a random x and y coordinates upon opening the application.

is there any such things like TextView.x = 30, and TextView = 30??

Answer (score 1):

Place the TextViews inside a **FrameLayout** and set their coordinates using **android:layout_marginTop** and **android:layout_marginLeft**. FrameLayout positions its items absolutely from the top left corner. You can work with the z-axis by changing the order of items in the layout - the first item lies below the second item and so on...

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

You can also set it dynamically from the code.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_textview);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.topMargin = 10; // margin in pixels, not dps
layoutParams.leftMargin = 10; // margin in pixels, not dps
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
 textView.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(100,40, 100, 70));
```

But here we can only use **AbsoluteLayout**, which is deprecated!